# is there anyway to fully prevent popstate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Im working with jquery mobile right now. And when the user clicks on the box, it will show an additional one. But when the user forced return on browser (or the backbutton), on that moment, the second box should hide, instead of going back the the prev page.

I've managed to achiev almost what I wanted with the popstate:

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
  if($('div').is(':visible') {
     closeFunction();
     event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  }
}
```

But it still changes the URL.

For example, if i has a nav like this:

```
index > home > internal(with box)
```

And then i pressed the back button

```
index > home
```

Will still trigger the url change, but not the page change.

I've tried with pagebeforechange, but with the same result.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've managed to workaround with a fake pushstate with the active page url.

Answer (score 2):

the popstate event is not cancellable. 
referred [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate)

> Specification: HTML5
>   Interface: PopStateEvent
>   Bubbles: Yes
>   Cancelable: No
>   Target: defaultView
>   Default Action: None